# Blazor button, use parent component @onclick

Tags: blazor

Is it possible to use the parent component method @onclick, or do I need to invoke it from the child?

Let's say I want to invoke parent method Foo().

**Parent**

```cs
@page "/"

// Custom component button
<Button Text="Some text" @onclick="Foo" Apperance="@Style.secondary" /> 


@code {
    async Task Foo() 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Child**

```cs
<button class="btn @_cssClass"><span>@Text</span></button>

@code {
    public enum Style
    {
        primary,
        secondary,
        tertiary,
        danger
    }

    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public Style Apperance { get; set; }
    private string _cssClass { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _cssClass = Apperance switch
        {
            Style.secondary => "btn--secondary",
            Style.tertiary => "btn--tertiary",
            Style.danger => "btn--danger",
            _ => "btn--primary"
        };
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Object of type 'Tidrapport.Client.Components.Button' does not have a property matching the name 'onclick'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'Tidrapport.Client.Components.Button' does not have a property matching the name 'onclick'.
```

I do want a child-button component, and when it's clicked (rendered in parent) - I want to invoke a method in the parent component.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I've found the answer to my question, you design an `EventCallback` found in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#eventcallback).

So for me, it looks like this.

**Parent**

```cs
@page "/"

// Custom component button
<Button Text="Some text" OnClickCallback="@Foo" Apperance="@Style.secondary" /> 

@code {
    async Task Foo() 
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Child**

```cs
<button class="btn @_cssClass" @onclick="OnClickCallback"><span>@Text</span></button>

@code {
    public enum Style
    {
        primary,
        secondary,
        tertiary,
        danger
    }

    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public Style Apperance { get; set; }
    private string _cssClass { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback OnClickCallback { get; set; } // this is where to you pass the parent function to be executed as a callback

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _cssClass = Apperance switch
        {
            Style.secondary => "btn--secondary",
            Style.tertiary => "btn--tertiary",
            Style.danger => "btn--danger",
            _ => ""
        };
    }
}
```

So the onclick event is bound to the eventhandler you design in the child component. It can be of type `T` if you want to use arguments, more on that in the docs.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [attribute splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/splat-attributes-and-arbitrary-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0) which lets you continue using the Razor `@onclick` attribute instead of declaring a callback.

Just add the following to your child class:

1. A parameter that captures unmatched values
2. The `@attributes` Razor attribute on the child element.

For example, have a `Button.razor` file that looks like this:

```razor
<button class="btn" @attributes="AdditionalAttributes">@Text</button>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```razor
<Button Text="Some text" @onclick="Foo" />
```

Note that this will apply all unmatched attributes, not just `@onclick`, and will overwrite any attributes that were declared before it. This may not be desirable in some situations, in which case you can just use an `EventCallback`.

Comment: Imo this is the only correct answer, assuming you don't need any custom parameters or something in your callback.

Comment: The link to the docs is no longer up to date. Attribute splatting is no longer a section on the "Components" page, but now has its own page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/splat-attributes-and-arbitrary-parameters

Comment: @Napoleon - why do you consider it the "only" correct answer? Sure it works, but so does the accepted answer, and both take the same amount of coding. I personally prefer the EventCallback method, as it feels more straightforward, and also keeps my code uniform by sticking with a single method for all callbacks, whether they require parameters or not

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the @onclick directive that way... This directive is used with Html elements, instructing the compiler to create event handler for the click event, as for instance:

```
<button type="button" @onclick="ClickEventHandler">Click me</button>

@code{
   private void ClickEventHandler()
   {
      Cosole.WriteLine("Hello Blazor");
    }
}
```

When you bind components, however, you should do something like this:

### ChildComponent.razor

```
<input type="text" @bind="Text" @bind:event="oninput" />

@code {
        private string text { get; set; }

        [Parameter]
        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set
            {
                if (text != value) {
                    text = value;
                    if (TextChanged.HasDelegate)
                    {
                        TextChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback<string> TextChanged { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, I've defined a parameter Property named Text... In order to create two-way data binding, you should also define an EventCallback 'delegate' whose role is to update the bound object in the parent component. Thus, in the parent component you'll code:

```
<ChildComponent @bind-Text="Text" />
```

Note that the EventCallback delegate's name is composed of the Text word plus the word Changed.

The instruction @bind-Text binds the Text property defined in the child component to the Text property (see code below) defined in the parent component.

Thus the rule is `@bind-` plus the name of a property in the child component, as for instance `Value` which goes to `@bind-Value` and whose value should be the name of a property, say, `MyValue` and thus: `@bind-Value="MyValue"`

In the child component, however, you should define a parameter property named Value and an `EventCallback` named `ValueChanged`...

Here's a complete working code snippet demonstrating two-way data binding between a parent component and its child:

### ParentComponent.razor

```
@page "/ParentComponent"

<h1>Parent Component</h1>

<input type="text" @bind="Text" @bind:event="oninput" />
<p></p>

<ChildComponent @bind-Text="Text" />


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; } = "Hello Blazor";
}
```

Hope this works...

Comment: Thanks, but that's two-way data binding with strings, which is not what I'm after. Maybe I was a bit unclear. So, I do want a child-button component, and when it's clicked - I want to invoke a method in the parent compent.

Answer (score 2):

> So, I do want a child-button component, and when it's clicked - I want to invoke a method in the parent compent.

You ChildComponent should look like this:

```
<button type="button" @onclick="CallMethodParent">Call a method on parent component</button>


    @code {
    
        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback<string> ParentMethod { get; set; }
    
        private async Task CallMethodParent()
        {
            if(ParentMethod.HasDelegate)
            {
              await  ParentMethod.InvokeAsync("A message from child component...");
            }
        }
    
    }
```

### Usage

```
<p>@message</p>

<ChildComponent ParentMethod="ParentMethod"/>

@code{
    private string message;

    private void ParentMethod(string message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Note: The main thing to take from this is that you should define a parameter EventCallback property in the child component, which stores a method defined in the parent component.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank's again for the comment, just saw it after I found the solution.