# How to send property to method in blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-component

My DataTables component:

```
            <span>
                @foreach (var paginateButton in paginateButtonList)
                {
                    <PaginateButton @bind-IsCurrent="paginateButton.IsCurrent" @onclick="@(() => method(paginateButton))"></PaginateButton> 
                }
            </span>
    @code {
    
        IList<PaginateButton> paginateButtonList = new List<PaginateButton>()
        {
            new PaginateButton(){Name = "1"},
            new PaginateButton(){Name = "2"},
            new PaginateButton(){Name = "3"}
        };
    
    
        void method(PaginateButton pb)
        {
    
        }
    
        DataTablesRequest dataTablesRequestModel = new DataTablesRequest();
    }
```

When I send paginateButton to method, I am getting an error:

> 'DataTablesBlazorVersion.Components.DataTables.PaginateButton' does
> not have a property matching the name 'onclick'.

Comment: [at]onclick is a directive used in html elements. It looks like you've trying to apply it to a Blazor Component.  See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62448581/blazor-button-use-parent-component-onclick.